# POST cURL turns to GET cURL

Tags: java, reactjs, curl, postman

I've an app which are used springboot in backend and react in frontend. Everything works correctly in app. Only I wonder that when cURL are taken over chrome and edge, then are used in postman, It turns to GET request. I don't understand why it turns to GET request. (Step 3 in shared image)

To repeat the scenario. I summarized my codes.

For Backend:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class TestApi {
  @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
  public void uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile multipartFile) {
      System.out.println(multipartFile.getName());
  }
}
```

For Frontend :

```
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';  
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'; 
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';    
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';  
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function ManagementAuth() {  
   const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState([]);    

   const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
      setImageFile(event.target.files[0]);
   }; 

const fileUploadHandler = (event) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('multipartFile', imageFile, imageFile.name);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/uploadFile', fd)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}; 

return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <CssBaseline />
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={0}
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}
                >        
                <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '35ch' }} variant="standard"> 
                    <input type="file" onChange={fileSelectedHandler}/>
                    <button onClick={fileUploadHandler}>Upload</button>
                </FormControl>     
            </Grid> 
        </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default ManagementAuth;
```

After run two app,

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmzfy.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e39Qg.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsBQB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would make this as a comment, but I cant comment yet. A quick search turned this up
[https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-My-request-is-redirected-to-a-GET-request#:~:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20open%20the,Follow%20original%20HTTP%20method%20option](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/211913929-My-request-is-redirected-to-a-GET-request#:%7E:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20open%20the,Follow%20original%20HTTP%20method%20option).

You are experiencing one of the following issues

- **All of your requests are sent as GET requests,** no matter which HTTP request method you select.
- The original HTTP request method you selected is not preserved when there is a redirect between HTTP and HTTPS.

What to expect

Postman automatically redirects requests that return a 3xx response. Note: To check for a 3xx response, use the Postman console and verify whether it shows a 3xx response. If so, it indicates a redirection. If not, submit a support request (see below).

How to unblock yourself

- Disable the automatic redirection for 3xx responses. To do this, open the Settings tab of your request and toggle off the Automatically follow redirects option.
- Force your request to follow the original HTTP method. To do so, open the Settings tab of the request and toggle on the Follow original HTTP method option.
- If your API service provider uses Nginx as a web server, add a trailing slash ( / ) on the request URL.
- If none of these options help, reach out to your API service provider for assistance.

Comment: I've seen this link before and I tried everything that mentioned in text and doesn't fix it. only when I tried with post curl without file sending (json request body, path variable, request params etc.), I take correct request method. Namely, It doesn't turns to GET Request. Only when I try file sending, It turns to get request

Comment: Hm, strange. If you select  'Preserve Log' under devtools what does it say is happening? Also, is it intentional that in your third photo it is an http request instead of https?

Comment: unfortunately, anything didn't changed with preserve log and there isn't any error in all logs. everything works correctly. for your second questions, It is intentional. Actually, I tried in other environment which is had https as url and I took the same result.

Comment: And when you track 'https://localhost:8080/uploadFile', a trailing slash isn't added? I know that can be an issue. ie: it redirects 300 or 301 status code. Might want to try going to the settings tab inside the request and enabling the "Follow original HTTP Method".

Comment: yes, additionally I tried again all methods that are mentioned in your text and nothing changed.

Comment: Then I apologize, for I am out of my league here. Best of luck though, and hopefully someone else will have an idea!